# Using this.prototype in a class definition?

Tags: javascript

I have a class definition that is part of a class definition.

```
var someObject = {
   someClass: function() {
      this.someMethod = function() {
         alert('hello');
      };
   }
}
```

I have been told that I should use prototype to add methods, as it then only needs to be created once for all instances of the object. The problem is that it seems I need to add the prototyped method *after* the constructor function is defined, like this...

```
var someObject = {
   someClass: function() {

   }
}

someObject.someClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
   alert('hello');
};
```

Ideally however I would like to define the prototyped methods within the constructor function like this...

```
var someObject = {
   someClass: function() {
      this.prototype.someMethod = function() {
         alert('hello');
      };
   }
}
```

This causes an error however stating that prototype is null or not an object. Is there a way to accomplish what I would like, or is this not possible?

Comment: Prototype doesn't really work that way.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory can you elaborate?

Comment: of course you get error because  "this" represents the instance of that object and not the "definition" of that object or its properties or methods.

Comment: @Birey `this` represents the object being created when the function is called like this `var object = new someObject.someClass();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by using `arguments.callee` or - if you don't overwrite the `.prototype` property of your constructor function - `this.constructor` instead of plain `this`, ie

```
var someObject = {
   someClass: function() {
      // this.constructor.prototype should work as well
      arguments.callee.prototype.someMethod = function() {
         alert('hello');
      };
   }
};
```

However, putting the function expression back into the constructor defeats the whole purpose of the exercise - it doesn't matter that you store the reference to the function object in the prototype instead of the instance, you're still creating a new one on each constructor invocation!

One possible solution is using an anonymous constructor instead of an object literal, which gets you an additional scope for free:

```
var someObject = new (function() {
    function someClass() {}

    someClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
        alert('hello');
    };

    this.someClass = someClass;
});
```

See [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172546/using-this-prototype-in-a-class-definition/8172624#8172624) for an equivalent solution using object literals and a wrapper function, which might be more familiar.

Comment: I understand now. Comming from a different language background, it didn't wuite click at first. so simple now that I think about it. the reason prototype only gets called once is because it is outside of the constructor. i like the idea you have about turning the original object into an anonymous constructor so that I can put prototyped methods there instead of after the initial object definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't access prototype property inside the constructor of the class, but you can do a little bit different code notation, so probably it helps to you:

```
var someObject = {
   someClass: (function wrapper() {
      var ctor = function(){};
      ctor.prototype.someMethod = function(){
        alert('hello');
      };
      return ctor;
   })()
}
```