# javascript prototype declaration

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

There are two pieces of codes.

Why is the first one correct but the second one incorrect?

What's wrong with `this.prototype`?

```
function Person(name, age, job){

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.job = job;

    if (typeof this.sayName != "function"){

        Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
            alert(this.name);
        };

    }
}
```

---

```
function Person(name, age, job){

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.job = job;

    if (typeof this.sayName != "function"){

        this.prototype.sayName = function(){
            alert(this.name);
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using this.prototype in a class definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172546/using-this-prototype-in-a-class-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are actually incorrect. But more on that later.

The second one is incorrect because objects don't have `prototype` property. [Only **functions** have a such a property](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.2).

In the second example, `this` is an object, so `this.prototype` is `undefined`. In the first example you are setting `Person.prototype` and `Person` is a function, so all is "good".

---

Why is the first example still wrong? Because you usually don't have a reason to extend the prototype object *inside* the constructor. The constructor should only contain *instance specific* code and the prototype object should hold properties which are *shared* by all instances.

So your above example is correctly written as:

```
function Person(name, age, job){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.job = job;
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};
```

Comment: This is conceptually wrong, every object in JS do has [[Prototype]] property to be modified with. Function as an object in JS has no exception.

Comment: @Felix Kling: it's not necessarily *wrong* to assign prototype methods within the constructor function, it just seems to be 'not done', which is never an argument to not do something ;). Within the constructor the OP could use `if (!Person.prototype.sayName) {...}`.

Comment: @miushock: Did I say anywhere it doesn't have a `[[Prototype]]` property? I said `prototype` property, which only functions have.

Comment: @KooiInc: That's why I said *usually*. But I have to admit that I say it's incorrect in my first sentence ;) I'd say it's a rare thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's about how prototype is implemented.

When you saying Person.prototype.sayName 'Person.prototype' gives you the [[Prototype]] property of 'Person' to be modified with.

when calling this.prototype.sayName a property named 'prototype' is checked for 'this' object and if not found the object referenced by [[Prototype]] property of 'this', which is still not found cause you haven't defined it

P.S.

Haven't tested myself, but this.__proto__ shall work in some implementations

Comment: You are confusing things here (I think?). The `prototype` property of a function has nothing to do with the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the function. What is correct is that the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the newly created instance of `Person` is set to `Person.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

in `this.prototype` you are referring to the instance. The instance has no prototype, the constructor function does. You can replace:

```
if (typeof this.sayName != "function"){
        this.prototype.sayName = function(){
            alert(this.name);
        };
}
```

with

```
if (!Person.prototype.sayName) {
        Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
            alert(this.name);
        };
}
```

A method assigned to the prototpe will exist within all derived instances. `this.sayName` in the first snippet doesn't exist on first instantiation, but your `if ...` catches it and  assigns `Person.prototype.sayName`, which is subsequently available to new instances of `Person`. That's why the first example works.