# Understanding JavaScript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
Block = function (){
 this.type = 'block';
 if(arguments[0]) this.type = arguments[0];

 this.location = {x: 0, y: 0};
 function update(){

   }
}

Empty = function(location){
this.prototype = new Block;

this.type = 'empty';
this.location = location;
}
```

I want to be able to call

```
var x = new Empty();
x.update();
```

But I get the error that x.update is not a function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22292881/218196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype property is only useful on a function. In the Empty constructor you're setting it on each instance of Empty, so it basically does nothing.

A much better way to do inheritance with JavaScript than what you're trying to do is to set the prototype of the inheriting class to inherit from the prototype of the base class:

```
Empty.prototype = Object.create(Block.prototype);
```

... and in order to inherit the properties set in the base class constructor, you simply call it with the correct arguments in the inheriting class constructor:

```
Empty = function(location) {
  Block.call(this, location); // call base class
  // other code, specific to your inheriting class
}
```

Note that the Empty.prototype line should come after you define Empty:

```
Empty = function(location) {
  Block.call(this, location); // call base class
  // other code, specific to your inheriting class
}
Empty.prototype = Object.create(Block.prototype);
```

Finally, to make methods available to instances you can define them in the constructor for each instance:

```
Block = function() {
  this.update = function() { };
}
```

... or on the prototype of the constructor (after you define the constructor, obviously):

```
Block.prototype.update = function() {};
```

I don't know your particular scenario, but it seems to me that your inheritance is slightly weird. Usually the base is the more generic type (with variable location) and the inheriting class specializes it. The base class would be Doctor (person who treats diseases) and the inheriting class would be Dentist (person who treats certain kinds of diseases).

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

My example is probably bad, I have a lot of different types of 'block' objects, Empty is one type of block.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the prototype of `this` inside the constructor (where it would point to the new object, which doesn't have a prototype property with any meaning), you set it on the constructor directly (`Block` in this case).

Also, `update` is *hidden* in your case. You need to assign it to `this` (not so great practice) or make it part of `Block`'s prototype, which you should, otherwise there is no real point using delegation or inheritance here.

Your code should look more or less like...

```
var Block = function () {
    this.type = 'block';
    if (arguments[0]) this.type = arguments[0];
    this.location = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
};

Block.prototype.update = function () {
    console.log("updating");
};

var Empty = function (location) {
    this.type = 'empty';
    this.location = location;
};

Empty.prototype = new Block;

var x = new Empty();
x.update();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2USJR/).